# ManyToMany table with 3 related tables

Tags: java, jpa, uml

I have this UML Diagram:

[image]

And I do entities like this (and like others that works correctly)

**Entity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class Entidad extends BaseEntity {

    protected String name;

    protected String image;

    protected String foundationNotes;

    protected String alias;

    protected Boolean excludeNotifications;

    protected String notes;

    //[...]

    @OrderBy("id")
    @ManyToMany
    protected Set<EntityHeader> headersType = new HashSet<EntityHeader>();

    //[...]

    @OrderBy("id")
    @ManyToMany
    protected Set<Member> candidatures = new HashSet<Member>();

    @OrderBy("id")
    @ManyToMany
    protected Set<Proposal> proposals = new HashSet<Proposal>();

    //[Getters and Setters]
```

**Proposal.java**

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "proposal")
    public class Proposal implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Entidad entity;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Candidature candidature;

    @ManyToOne
    private SendMethod sendMethod;

    //[Getters and Setters]
```

**Candidature.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "candidature")
public class Candidature extends BaseEntity {

    private String reference;

    private Integer year;

    private Date date;

    private Boolean accepted;

    private Boolean supports;

    private String notes;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    private ScopeCandidature scope;

    @OrderBy("id")
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Proposal> proponents = new HashSet<Proposal>();

    @OrderBy("id")
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Member> members = new HashSet<Member>();

    //[Getters and setters]
```

But when I try to compile it throws

> Foreign key (FK_ffsm4eg8pctsa9yuvqm4kq1my:send_method [])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (proposal [entity_id,candidature_id])

I think the problem is in `SendMethod` column, because I have more intermediate tables (i.e. `headersType` called in **Entity.java**) and works fine, so I don't know how to do this with a 3 table relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem, In entity `SendMethod` I have:

```
@ManyToOne
private Proposal proposal;
```

When I removed It works fine.